# htacces rewrite url - redirect folder to php file

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect or rewrite sub directories to PHP files

Such as:

```
http://www.domain.org/contact
```

to this:

```
http://www.domain.org/index.php?sub=contact
```

I would REALLY like it is PHP could just read domain.org/contact as domain.org/index.php?sub=contact, but if it just redirects that way I'll be happy!  I've searched for many solutions using .htaccess, but they are unclear or I can't get them to work specifically for what I am attempting to do

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?sub=$1
```